# Go up one node and see if the parent node equates a particular node in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

I want to see if the parent node of the current node I am referring to is equal to a particular value. I did it as follows but no use.

eg.

```
<v:name>
<v:age>
```

when at "age" I tried `<xsl:if test='.. = v:name'>`. But it is not correct. What is the correct way? Can someone help?

I am inside a template which is true for both v:name and v:age. There are v:age's which are not children of v:name. I want to ensure that v:age I am referring to is a child of a v:name. That is what I want inside the test attribute.

Comment: Please post a sample of the XML you have and the XML or HTML or plain text result you want, unless simply doing `<xsl:if test="parent::v:name and self::v:age">...</xsl:if>`. However it looks to me as if writing a template `<xsl:template match="v:name/v:age">...</xsl:template>` is a better, more XSLT like approach to handle such checks.

Comment: This needs a bit more context. Please post sample input document, expected output and any style-sheet you have so far. It may well be that you can avoid the <xsl:if> altogether with an appropriate predicate on the template pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a comment by the OP:

> I am inside a template which is true for both `v:name` and `v:age`.
>   There are `v:age`'s which are not children of `v:name`. I want to
>   ensure that `v:age` I am referring to is a child of a `v:name`. That
>   is what I want inside the test attribute

**Use**:

```
parent::v:name
```

And this in a `xsl:if` becomes:

```
<xsl:if test="parent::v:name">
  <!-- Whatever processing is necessary. -->
</xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `<xsl:if test="../v:name = 'somevalue'></xsl:if>` or `<xsl:if test="parent::v:name = 'somevalue'></xsl:if>`

Comment: I am inside a template which is true for both v:name and v:age. There are v:age's which are not children of v:name. I want to ensure that v:age I am referring to is a child of a v:name. That is what I want inside the test attribute.

Comment: `<xsl:if test="name(parent::node()) = 'v:name'"><!-- magic --></xsl:if>`

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that when you say you want to know if the parent node is "equal" to a particular value, you really mean that you want to know whether its name is equal to a particular value (this would be immediately clear if you gave examples of your input and output).

If my conjecture is correct, use `<xsl:if test="parent::xyz">`